# Как вывести текущее время в терминал с помощью asm?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm

У меня в программе есть код:

```
gettime:

    mov eax, 13
    xor ebx, ebx

    int 0x80 ; получили текущее время в секундах

    mov [time], eax ; сохранили в переменную

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, time
    mov edx, 8


    int 0x80 ; вывели на экран

    jmp read ; к другой метке
```

Но он ничего не выводит. Никакого текущего времени в секундах в терминале нет. Как его вывести?

Comment: В ecx должен быть указатель на строку (массив символов), а вы туда кладете указатель на целое число.

Comment: @insolor Все равно вывода времени нет изменил переменную time на "", 10, 0

Comment: Ну так вы потом затираете это значение бинарными данными по сути, оно так не отобразится. Вам нужно преобразовать целое число в текст, например той же функцией sprintf из libc, потом уже отображать через этот системный вызов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сначала преобразовать целое 4-байтовое число в строку, а потом уже эту строку выводить на экран.

На практике я бы посоветовал использовать функцию sprintf из стандартной библиотеки Си, но можно перекодировать и вручную:

```
section .bss
    buf resb 250 

section .text
global _start
_start:
gettime:

    mov eax, 13
    xor ebx, ebx

    int 0x80 ; получили текущее время в секундах

    ; mov eax, 123456 ; для тестирования раскомментировать

    mov edi, buf
    call dword_to_udec_str
    ; при выходе из процедуры в данном случае в edi находится адрес конца строки,
    ; из конца вычитаем начало - получаем длину
    sub edi, buf

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, buf
    mov edx, edi

    int 0x80 ; вывели на экран

    ; Выход
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h

;Процедура преобразования двойного слова в строку в десятичном виде (без знака)
; EAX - двойное слово
; EDI - буфер для строки. Значение регистра не сохраняется.
dword_to_udec_str:
    xor ecx,ecx               ;Обнуление CX
    mov ebx,10               ;В EBX делитель (10 для десятичной системы)
 
wtuds_lp1:                  ;Цикл получения остатков от деления
    xor edx,edx               ;Обнуление старшей части двойного слова
    div ebx                  ;Деление EAX=(EDX:EAX)/EBX, остаток в EDX
    add dl, '0'              ;Преобразование остатка в код символа
    push rdx                 ;Сохранение в стеке
    inc ecx                  ;Увеличение счетчика символов
    test eax,eax              ;Проверка EAX на 0
    jnz wtuds_lp1           ;Переход к началу цикла, если частное не 0.
 
wtuds_lp2:                  ;Цикл извлечения символов из стека
    pop rdx                  ;Восстановление символа из стека
    mov [edi],dl             ;Сохранение символа в буфере
    inc edi                  ;Инкремент адреса буфера
    loop wtuds_lp2          ;Команда цикла
    ret
```

Для перекодирования использован адаптированный пример с сайта fasmworld: [Учебный курс. Часть 22. Вывод чисел на консоль](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/022-vyvod-chisel-na-konsol/)