# Как подготавливается буфер для системного вызова write. Сумма это целое число, а в буфере набор кодов. Как из одного получается другое?

Tags: ассемблер, буферизация, gnu-assembler

```
.text
  movl $4, %eax # номер сист. вызова write
  movl $1, %ebx # параметр 1: дескриптор стандартного вывода
  movl $\number, %ecx # параметр 2: адрес памяти с выводимыми цифрами
  movl $\rank, %edx # параметр 3: количество байтов для вывода
  int $0x80 # выполнить системный вызов
.endm
```

Comment: чтобы переносились строки, нужно добавить два пробела в конце строки, а затем уже enter; Теперь по вопросу: что это за ассемблер ?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как вывести текущее время в терминал с помощью asm?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106877/Как-вывести-текущее-время-в-терминал-с-помощью-asm)

Comment: Нужно перекодировать число в набор символов вручную (как в ответе по ссылке выше) или с помощью функции sprintf из libc, например.

Comment: @santavital, принудительный перенос для форматирования кода - это плохой способ. Для форматирования кода нужно или добавить отступ в 4 пробела (выделить код и нажать кнопку `{}` над редактором вопроса/ответа), или добавить ``` до и после кода. См. справку: [Код и предварительно отформатированный текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)